# How to return "TRUE" after deleting all files in a folder on my server?

Tags: php

I have this function that deletes the content of a folder:

```
// Delets the content of the "files/weekly_reports/" folder.
public function delete_pdf(){

        // get all file names
        $files = glob('files/weekly_reports/*'); 

        foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files

            if(is_file($file))
            unlink($file); // delete file

            }
        }
```

When running this function in a for loop, the PHP Code continues running although it hasn't finished the delete process (I think), and as a result - jumps over processes because it returns FALSE.

so I added an other part:

```
// Delets the content of the "files/weekly_reports/" folder.
public function delete_pdf(){

    // get all file names
    $files = glob('files/weekly_reports/*'); 

    foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files

        if(is_file($file))
        unlink($file); // delete file

    }


    if (empty($files)){
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

so I get the same result.

How can I make sure that the folder is 100% empty and get the loop running without any problems.

For curious people, here is the main code that calls the function:

```
public function main_weekly_report(){

    $today = date('Y-m-d');

    $reports = $this->kas_model->get_wr_table();

    foreach ($reports as $report) {

        // Outputs the current report that it is on. 
        var_dump($report);

        // Delete the content of the folder containing the PDFs
        if ($this->delete_pdf()){

            // Creates a new PDF
            $this->create_pdf($report->wr_app_id, $report->wr_date1, $report->wr_date2, $report->wr_date3);

            // Increment "dates" to next week.
            // $this->kas_model->weekly_inc_date($report->wr_id, 'wr_date1', $today);
            // $this->kas_model->weekly_inc_date($report->wr_id, 'wr_date2', $today);

            // Sends to the report to the customer:
            if ( $this->is_connected() ) {
                $this->send_pdf_customer($report->wr_app_id);
                echo "Sent to customer!";
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, `if (empty($files)){`, `$files` is still the same array of file names that you got in `$files = glob('files/weekly_reports/*');`.

Unlinking the file removes a reference to the file in the file system, but doesn't affect the contents of the array you have in memory.

You could repopulate it by running the `glob()` again in your test at the end of the method.

Comment: I added this and now it sends the first file. the second time it sends 2 files, then it send 3 files, ect', What da hell?

Comment: Is that in your `main_weekly_report()` method? If so that sounds like a separate question to me than "why is `delete_pdf()` always returning false"?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right. You just missed to `unset()` the element after deleting it in filesystem. Try this in your `foreach`.

```
foreach($files as $key=>$file){ // iterate files

    if(is_file($file))
    {
      if(unlink($file))
      {
         unset($files[$key]);
      } // delete file
    }
}
```

So then, this will work

```
if (empty($files)){
   return TRUE;
} else {
   return FALSE;
}
```

Output: TRUE

Comment: I used `$files = glob('files/weekly_reports/*');` again before the `if (empty(...` and now I get the first file sent, then the first and the second file sent, then the first, second and third file sent...