# PHP+CodeIgniter+SMTP: Why sending files within a loop using SMTP stacks attachments instead of sending them separately

Tags: php, email

I have this function that sends emails to customers from a folder `files/weekly reports`.

```
// Sends the "Weekly Report.pdf" file (from /files/weekly reports)
public function send_pdf_customer($prod_id){

    if ($this->is_connected()){

        $prod_row = $this->kas_model->get_prod_row_by_id($prod_id);

        var_dump($prod_row[0]->prod_client_email);

        $email = $prod_row[0]->prod_client_email;

        // All recipients who get the email. 
        //$recipients = "me@example.com, may@example.pro, daniel.m@exmaple.com, maayan@exmaple.pro";
        // $recipients = "me@example.com";
        $recipients = $email;

        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from('me@example.pro', 'example - weekly Report');
        $this->email->to($recipients);
        //$this->email->bcc($recipients);
        $this->email->subject('example - weekly Report');
        $this->email->message('Currently on test mode. Please update if you find any errors.');  
        $this->email->attach("files/weekly_reports/$prod_id-Weekly_report.pdf");
        // SEND
        $this->email->send(); 

        return TRUE;

    } 

}
```

As you can see, I have this line:

```
$this->email->attach("files/weekly_reports/$prod_id-Weekly_report.pdf");
```

which clearly points to the file.

This is the main function that calls the send function:

public function main_weekly_report(){

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');

$reports = $this->kas_model->get_wr_table();

foreach ($reports as $report) {

    // Outputs the current report that it is on. 
    var_dump($report);

    // Delete the content of the folder containing the PDFs
    if ($this->delete_pdf()){

        // Creates a new PDF
        $this->create_pdf($report->wr_app_id, $report->wr_date1, $report->wr_date2, $report->wr_date3);

        // Increment "dates" to next week.
        // $this->kas_model->weekly_inc_date($report->wr_id, 'wr_date1', $today);
        // $this->kas_model->weekly_inc_date($report->wr_id, 'wr_date2', $today);

        // Sends to the report to the customer:
        if ( $this->is_connected() ) {
            $this->send_pdf_customer($report->wr_app_id);
            echo "Sent to customer!";
        }
    }

}
```

}

The result of this is:

the first file in the email (6-Weekly_report.pdf),

then the first AND the second file via different email (6-Weekly_report.pdf && 7-Weekly_report.pdf),

then the first, second and the third file different email ( 6-Weekly_report.pdf && 7-Weekly_report.pdf && 8-Weekly_report.pdf )... ect'.

Why is it stacking the files instead of sending them separably?

Why is it stacking the files instead of sending them separably although I delete the files using a different function? (the function works too, I had a post on it here too: [How to return "TRUE" after deleting all files in a folder on my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008741/how-to-return-true-after-deleting-all-files-in-a-folder-on-my-server))

Using the delete/send functions outside the current one won't help me, because for each they send to different custumer.

I have this .php file in my config folder which the controller uses:

```
<?php 
            $config['protocol']  = "smtp";
            $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
            $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
            $config['smtp_user'] = "my@email.com"; 
            $config['smtp_pass'] = "hello";
            $config['charset']   = "utf-8";
            $config['mailtype']  = "html";
            $config['newline']   = "\r\n";
            $config['crlf']      = "\r\n";
            $config['validate']  = FALSE;
?>
```

Can you please help me find a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being able to see the `load` function, it looks like it's stacking the PDF's because `$this->email` is the same instance every time the function is called. So when the function is called the second time, instead of creating a new email it's just re-using the old one and overriding all the previous settings, but attaching another file without removing the old one

Comment: I edited my question (bottom part) and added the file email.php content. Can you please help me find a workaround this problem? 

I cant change the way i send emails because I have all my server sending other emails using this.

Comment: ey, solved it: http://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-1900.html

I added `$this->email->clear(true);`
before all the `$this->email->somthing`s. and it clears everything.